# My django admin page gives Page not found (404)

Tags: django, django-admin

my project was running ok I used my admin page at it was all all right today I tried to open it and it gives a Page not found (404)
No Product matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Raised by:  store.views.product_detail
No Product matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Raised by:  store.views.product_detail

I havent touched the store app or project files at all at it was waking just fine yesterday now i cannot access admin page
project urls

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    path('', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),
    path('basket/', include('basket.urls', namespace='basket')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace = 'account')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

store urls

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_all, name='product_all'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('shop/<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_list, name='category_list'),
]
```

store views

````
from urllib import request
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from store.context_processors import categories

from .models import Category, Product


def product_all(request):
    products = Product.products.all()
    return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'products': products})


def category_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'store/products/category.html', {'category': category, 'products': products})


def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, in_stock=True)
    return render(request, 'store/products/single.html', {'product': product})  ```
````

context_processors.py wicht i have includet in my project settings

```
from .models import Category

def categories(request):
return {
'categories': Category.objects.all()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that causes the error

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

Change it to

```
path('detail/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

The `product_detail` just overwrites the `admin` URL